# Linear span of given vectors expresses a plane in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Given vectors $(1,  3,  5), (-2 , -6,  -10)$ and $(2,  6 , 10)$ determine whether the linear span of the above is a plane in $\mathbb R^3$.

The vectors are linearly dependent nd hence do not form a basis and it is known that the set of linearly dependent vectors in $R^2$ are collinear.

So based on the above can it be said that linearly dependent vectors in $R^3$ will form a plane.

Comment: You are right. The span a plane.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Your final sentence is incorrect. For example, the vectors $(1,0,0)$, $(2,0,0)$ and $(3,0,0)$ are linearly dependent, but their span is a line, not a plane. You need another condition to ensure that the span is a plane.

Comment: @amd But these vectors would only cover one dimension i.e. x axis?

Comment: Exactly. It _can’t_ be said that linearly-dependent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ will form a plane, contrary to your last sentence. They might, but you need other conditions besides linear dependence.

Comment: @amd sorry my bad got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. It can be more rigorously stated, considering that the equation of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ is :

$$Ax + By + Cz = 0$$

But since your given vectors are linearly dependent, you will arrive at such an equation, thus satisfying the known algebraic expression (form) of a plane.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @tendo No problem, welcome to the forum ! In order to "close" question you may use the tick button rewarding the answer you may find the most suitable and the vote buttons reward users ! I also edited your answer a bit, more about MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ok sure thank you